# Variable retaining old value when trying to reset it

Tags: ios, swift

I'm pretty new to Swift and programming, so this may seem pretty basic, but I haven't been able to locate an answer on StackOverflow or Google while trying to solve this issue today.

I'm create a basic life counter app for fun, but I'm having some trouble when I'm trying to reset the user's life totals. I'm able to add and subtract totals from the starting value, but when I run reset it the initial value is staying in memory.

For example, if player one has 9 life and player 2 has 0, if I hit the reset button both totals will show 10 (the default), however, if I subtract 1 from player 1 it will show 8 and if I added 1 to player 2 it would show 1 instead of 11.

I guess I need to pass the value from reset somehow or just put the default variable somewhere else? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var playerOneAdd: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playerOneMinus: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playerOneLife: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playerTwoMinus: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playerTwoPlus: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playerTwoLife: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resetButton: UIButton!

var playerOne = 10
var playerTwo = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playerOneLife.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14)
}

@IBAction func PlayerOnePlusButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    ++playerOne
    playerOneLife.text = String(playerOne)
}

@IBAction func playerOneMinusButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    --playerOne
    playerOneLife.text = String(playerOne)
}

@IBAction func playerTwoMinusButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    --playerTwo
    playerTwoLife.text = String(playerTwo)
}

@IBAction func playerTwoPlusButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    ++playerTwo
    playerTwoLife.text = String(playerTwo)
}

@IBAction func resetPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var playerOne = 10
    var playerTwo = 10
    playerOneLife.text = String(playerOne)
    playerTwoLife.text = String(playerTwo)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `var` again, you re-define the variable. You should just set it equal.

```
playerOne = 10
playerTwo = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `var` keyword in `resetPressed`:

```
@IBAction func resetPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    playerOne = 10
    playerTwo = 10
    playerOneLife.text = String(playerOne)
    playerTwoLife.text = String(playerTwo)
}
```

The `var` keyword defines a new variable.  Since the variables are declared inside of a function, they are local variables and they override the instance variables.  Local variables are local to a function, so the overridden variables aren't accessed in the other functions.

Comment: Ahh, I knew I was doing something odd. Thank you very much!